# MySQL query advice

Tags: sql, mysql

I am lost in MySQL documentation. I have a table with votes - it has these columns

- id
- song_id
- user_id
- created

I cannot find the query which will process the information and output the 10 most voted songs in a given time period.  What is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT id, song_id, COUNT(1) AS total
FROM votes
WHERE created BETWEEN [user_defined_start_date] AND [user_defined_end_date]
GROUP BY song_id
ORDER BY total DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

How exactly are you storing the votes?
Replace the words in [] below with the variables you want.

```
select song_id
from [table]
where created > to_date('[the date you want]', '[the format you want]') and created < to_date('[the date you want]', '[the format you want]')
order by [votes]
limit 10;
```